# Can't change error/message of DateTime field and get duplicate error

Tags: datetime, symfony, twig

I'm still on that `DateTime`-field and now I have those two problems.

I have two fields on one form `date_start` and `date_end` where both are defined like this:

#### Entity

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\DateTime( message="My error message" )
 */
protected $date_start;
```

#### Form Type

```php
->add('date_start', 'datetime', array(
        'label' => 'incoming',
        'date_widget' => 'single_text',
        'time_widget' => 'single_text',
        'date_format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        'with_seconds' => false,
        'required' => false,
    ) )
```

#### Twig Fields

```
{% block form_errors %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {% for error in errors %}
            <li>{{ error.messageTemplate }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_errors %}

{% block field_errors %}{{ block('form_errors') }}{% endblock %}
```

#### Twig Template

```html
{{ form_errors(form.date_start.date) }}
{{ form_errors(form.date_end.date) }}

<div class="row{% if form_errors(form.date_start.date) or form_errors(form.date_start.time) %} error{% endif %}">
    {{ form_label(form.date_end, null, { 'attr': {'class': '_hint'} }) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.date_end) }}
</div>
```

And this exactly the same again for `date_end`.

#### The problems

When I enter a wrong input for `date_start.date` **both** `<div>` get the error class and the **both** have the same error attached. This doesn't happen vice versa (`date_start.date` correct, but `date_end.date`not).

The second problem is that the error message shows always "**This value is not valid**" and the line `@Assert\DateTime( message="My error message" )` doesn't seem to have any effect. And I got no idea how to change this for both `date` and `time` separately.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your second problem,  the error message **"This value is not valid"** is set because of  data transformation failure which occurs before validation. So `@Assert` is  irrelevant actually. You can change the message by setting `invalid_message` option in form field declaration.